# Number of observations in different panel data regressions

Tags: econometrics

Given a balanced two-period panel data, with lets say 1000 observations on 500 individuals.

When you estimate a pooled OLS regression and first-differences regression is there a standard in the economics literature on how you should report number of observations.

It seems most natural for me to report 500 observations in the case of first-differences.

This might seem trivial. But better follow any standard if it exists.

Comment: I don't see how this could be reported as anything other than 500 observations. If you ran a fixed effects regression it would be 1,000 observations but would also have 500 more parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is reasonable to show both observations and number of units of analysis. For instance, take [this example](http://economics.mit.edu/files/5677) of an article in the American Economic Review:

[image]

There is the row **Observations**, and the row **Countries**. The latter is the unit of analysis. As the data is a longitudinal panel, there are multiple observations per country. As the panel is unbalanced, the number of observations is generally not a multiple of the number of countries (e.g. for Pooled OLS (column 1), $945/150=6.3$).

Answer (score 2):

It is conventional to report both the total number of **observations** (1000 in your case) and the number of **groups** (500 in your case). If you want or are allowed to report only one number as the number of **observations**, it is suitable to report 1000 for POLS because POLS doesn't mind the fact that it is a panel data set. For FD, it is slightly confusing to me to say that the number of observations is 500. I would probably ask again of the writer what 500 means.